# index.html not rendering servlet 3.0 Tomcat 7

Tags: java, html, tomcat, servlet-3.0

I have a simple web app using Servlet 3.0 using Tomcat 7.0.25 and deploying the app as a war (mywebapp.war).

The war structure is as below:

- `mywebapp/index.html`
- `mywebapp/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
- `mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes/org/iq/adapter/ServerAdapter.class`

`index.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>my web app</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Your server is Up and Running</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

`ServerAdapter.java`:

```java
package org.iq.adapter;

@WebServlet(name="ServerAdapter", urlPatterns="/adapter/*")
public class ServerAdapter extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(this.getClass()+"::doGet called");
    }

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println(this.getClass()+"::doPost called");
    }
}
```

When I try to access mywebapp from browser using the below links:

- `localhost:8080/mywebapp` - I get a blank screen, index.html is not rendered - **WHY?** I guess since welcome file is not mentioned as I am not using a web.xml
- `localhost:8080/mywebapp/index.html` - I get a blank screen, index.html is still not rendered - **WHY?** I am lost
- `localhost:8080/mywebapp/adapter` - I get a blank screen, but I get the sysout on the server console as "class org.iq.adapter.ServerAdapter::doGet called" - **as expected**

Comment: try `localhost:8080/adapter/`

Comment: Which Status code do you get when trying to Access `localhost:8080/mywebapp/index.html`? And will that URL work, if you remove your Servlet? Anything interesting in your logs?

Comment: What do you get when you just use `http://localhost:8080/` and `http://localhost:8080/index.html`?

Comment: The servlet against url pattern "/adapter/*" is getting hit sucessfully as expected. Whats not working is the simple index.html. I am bit confused why you want me to try localhost:8080/adapter/. Anyways, i get HTTP Status 404 - /adapter

Comment: have you tried as @RealSkeptic suggested?

Comment: @slartidan The URL works if i remove the servlet. Nothing interesting in the logs. :(

Comment: RealSkeptic & Hiru http://localhost:8080/ shows the Tomcat's home page where as http://localhost:8080/index.html is 404

Comment: can you try using web.xml and adding link in welcome file

Answer (score 0):

Create a web.xml file in Web-INF folder like the following and add index.html in welcome files list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>

<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
    version="2.4">

 <welcome-file-list>  
   <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>  
    </welcome-file-list>  

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ServerAdapter </servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.iq.adapter.ServerAdapter </servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ServerAdapter </servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/adapter</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Kirti, I wish to do it without a web.xml. You might have missed the part of my question where I have mentioned "... I guess since welcome file is not mentioned as I am not using a web.xml...".

Comment: `welcome-file-list` should not be necessary, if using a complete URL (including `index.html` at the end)

Comment: there is separate web.xml from tomcat where the list of <welcome-file> is there.So i think it's not problem here

Comment: Slartidan and Hiru Agreed.